# Custom throttle unit test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following test:

```
import { throttle } from "./event";

jest.useFakeTimers();

it('mock setTimeout test', () => {
    const mockedFunction = jest.fn();
    throttle(mockedFunction, 1);
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(mockedFunction, 1000);
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

where throttle is:

```
export const throttle = (func, wait) => {
    let timer = null;
    return function(...args) {
        if (timer === null) {
            timer = setTimeout(() => {
                func.apply(this, args);
                timer = null;
            }, wait); 
        }
    };
};
```

but the test is failing:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is here, throttle will create for you a new function that 'add' a 'wait before' functionnality... you never called it

```
  throttle(mockedFunction, 1)();
```